# How to explain golang slice range's phenomenon

Tags: go, range, slice

```
type student struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]*student)
    s := []student{
        {Name: "Allen", Age: 24},
        {Name: "Tom", Age: 23},
    }

    for _, stu := range s {
        m[stu.Name] = &stu
    }
    fmt.Println(m)
    for key, value := range m {
        fmt.Println(key, value)
    }
}
```

result:

> map[Allen:0xc42006a0c0 Tom:0xc42006a0c0]
>
> Allen &{Tom 23}
>
> Tom &{Tom 23}

How to explain Slice's phenomenon, in my opinion, stu should be the address of every member of s, but from the results, s has the same address.

Comment: stu is a loop variable and exists only once: The variable (== the memory address) is reused on all iterations of the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The application is taking the address of the local variable `stu`.  Change the code to take the address of the slice element:

```
for i := range s {
    m[s[i].Name] = &s[i]
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/0izo4gGPV7